# JSONObject to XML conversion - empty lists not showing up in XML output

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a JSON string, which I am converting into a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

My JSON string has a some empty lists such as:

```
key:[]
```

Now I am creating XML string from this object:

```
String xmlString = XML.toString(jsonObject);
```

The issue is, the empty list keys in JSON are not showing up in XML at all. They should show up as empty tags in XML. How can I fix this?

Comment: What libraries do you use?

Comment: org.json, specifically http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot see <key></key> appearing, right? Go place a breakpoint in the file XML on line 408. Check out if the code within the else if is executed. Find the sourcecode: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/XML.java

Comment: On line 385, it should enter the else if block, because it checks if value.getClass().isArray() is true, which it is, because in debug mode, 'value' shows up as JSONArray. But it does not enter this, and goes to next line which sets 'value' to null and hence the tag is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer inspection of XML.java, it makes sense that a JSON key whose value is an empty list will not show up in XML output. For a JSON key that looks like:

```
key: ["val1","val2"]
```

the corresponding XML would be:

```
<key>val1</key>
<key>val2</key>
```

Since the list is empty, XML.java never enters the for loop and never prints out anything. This is correct behavior.

Thanks @LoreV for pointing me in the right direction.